# Align elements over background image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class=".black">
          <p>Search</p><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

The `li` elment has a background-image and I would like to place the contents of the `a`-tag at the bottom of the image. My example in the fiddle shows my attempt using flexbox but I am open to any suggestion that will support IE-9.

http://jsfiddle.net/pkc5v106/3/

So it´s the `.black`- class I need vertically-aligned at the bottom of the image with the `p` and `i`-tags aligned horizontally. Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can use `position:absolute;` and then give `position:relative;` to `li`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/pkc5v106/4/)